# Get Value From Dynamic Control in Page Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a dynamically created bill of material with each line item being a dynamic user_control. the user_control has a textbox for quantity entry. When I click the submit button i'd like to get all the quantities from each textbox but the controls have all disappeard on the page load and the page shows zero controls.

I know you can turn on autopostback for the textbox then catch each individual text_changed_event but that doesn't seem efficient. I'd like to just loop through all of them when user clicks submit button, then take them back to the same bill of material page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the reason why controls disappear on postback is that they were added to your page dynamically and when postback occurred the information about the dynamic controls were lost and page had no information about these dynamic controls.

Now about getting the values from controls inside dynamic user controls, you have use the `FindControl` method or have to iterate through the Controls collection of user control to get the reference to `TextBoxes`.

An idea about how to do this:

```
//1. Using ID of user control
//inside button_click method
protected void btnSubmit_Click(...)
{
     TextBox txt1 = idOfUserControl.FindControl(textBoxId);
}

//2. Using type of user control
//inside button_click method
protected void btnSubmit_Click(...)
{
     foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
        if(c is YourUserControlClass)
        {
             YourUserControlClass control = (YourUserControlClass)c;
             TextBox txt1 = c.FindControl(textBoxId);
        }
}
```